# How can i change the organization of my json?

Tags: javascript, json, object, data-manipulation

Hey i tried to transform a json file (as a js object but I can not do it). Here is an example of my problem:

*Input object*

```
{
    "peoples": [
        {
            "name": "Alain",
            "nationality": "Italian"
        },
        {
            "name": "John",
            "nationality": "French"
        },
        {
            "name": "FOO",
            "nationality": "French"
        }
    ]
}
```

*Output object*

```
{
    "nationality": {
        "french": {
            "peoples": [{ "name": "John" }, { "name": "FOO" }]
        },
        "italian": {
            "peoples": [{ "name": "Alain" }]
        }
    }
}
```

How can i do this ? maybe Lodash but i have not find any way to do this. Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple `reduce`:

```js
const obj = {
  "peoples": [{
      "name": "Alain",
      "nationality": "Italian"
    },
    {
      "name": "John",
      "nationality": "French"
    },
    {
      "name": "FOO",
      "nationality": "French"
    }
  ]
}

const output = obj.peoples.reduce((a, {nationality: n, ...rest}) => {
  const x = a.nationality[n]
  if (x) x.push(rest)
  else a.nationality[n] = [rest]
  return a
}, { nationality: {} })

console.log(output)
```

Note, I've used a spread operator to get the rest of the properties, so if you were to add more properties to each person, then those would be included in the new object.